# Order names in people picker

Tags: 2007, document-library, people-picker

Is there a way to order the names in a people picker?

In my Document Library a person's name is attached to the docuemt when it's uploaded and as you can see below the names are ordered by first name instead of surname, is there a way to change this?

The names are displayed as SURNAME, FIRST NAME [DEPARTMENT]

[image: people picker screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to change the sort order of standard people picker. This may be possible if you created your own control using code, but I'm unaware of any out-of-the-box method.

Cheers,
Kahle